# file not uploaded because of "content like scripting and navigation"

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am trying to upload an html file, a knit of an R markdown file, to a website. I get the message:  The file you are trying to attach (name-of-file.html) includes data that cannot be processed by the application. Please remove content like scripting and navigation, or retry with a different file format". Anyone understands what “content like scripting and navigation” means in this context and is there a solution?

Comment: Do you have a problem only with this html-file? An automatically generated #R Markdown (when you make a new .rmd file) is uploaded nice?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by " automatically generated #R Markdown". I tried a completely different file, and also - just saved the content that is there when you open a new Rmarkdown file - same message.

Comment: Have you any active content?

Comment: It loads data from my computer, then performs some analysis and visualization. But I don't think that would be an "active" content, because the file can be opened in different computers, that don't store the data.